# Multiple plots in matplotlib with a function returning a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generate_plot(data):
    plt.plot(...)
    return plt
```

we assume that _data is an iterable with length 4.

```
if "__name__" = "__main__":
   _data = ....
   plt.figure(1)
   for data_i, index in _data, range(4):
       plt.subplot(2,2,index+1)
       ??????? <---- what goes here?

   plt.savefig(...)
```

Can I call generate_plot such that the graph plotted is placed in position index?
If so, how?

To be honest, I don't quite understand how the plt object works in Matplotlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to `return plt`. You can think of `plt` just as a way to access all of the plotting things in matplotlib, not as a "plot object". Generate your data first, then plot it. Say for example I have

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generate_data():
    return np.random.randint(10, size=10)

plt.figure(1)
for i in range(4):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
    plt.plot(generate_data())

plt.show()
```

Comment: i currently have a very complicated function some else wrote which returns the plt. 
Let me try removing this and see.